# ASP.NET MVC3 Model Binding using IEnumerable (Cannot infer type from)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model

I have a model class (edited for brevity)

**Model Class**

```
public class GridModel
{
   public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
   public int OnHandQty     { get; set; }
}
public class Shipment
{
  public string shipTrackingNo               {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<GridModel> ItemsShipped { get; set;}
{
```

**cshtml page**

```
@model Namespc.Models.Shipment

<link href="../../Content/CSS/Grid/Grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/ECommerce.Grid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="_shipmentDetailGrid">
    <table class="TableStyle">
     <tr class="GridRowStyle">
       <td width="130px" ></td>
         @foreach (var Item in Model.ItemsShipped)
           {
             <td width="70px" align="center">
                   @html.LabelFor(item.OnHandQty) <-- Cannot infer type from usage
             </td>
           }
       </tr>
```

I want to be able to bind item.OnHandQty that resides in the IEnumerable collection. How can you have a Model class and also an IEnumerable collection of a custom class (or rather you own class)?

Answer (score 2):

Well, what is the type of the items stored in `ItemsShipped`? You should use the generic version of `IEnumerable` to indicate what types are stored within it.

If your class was named `Item`, you would declare it `IEnumerable<Item>` then, when iterating at run time, ie `@foreach (var Item in Model.ItemsShipped)`, the type of `Item` will be strongly-typed instead of a plain `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
@foreach (var Item in Model.ItemsShipped)
           {
             <td width="70px" align="center">
                   @html.LabelFor(item.OnHandQty) <-- Cannot infer type from usage
             </td>
           }
```

Do this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemsShipped)
```

Then create a custom display template (placed in `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/GridModel.cshtml`):

```
@model Namespc.Models.GridModel
<td width="70px" align="center">
   @html.LabelFor(model => model.OnHandQty)
</td>
```

I've got a feeling it's not working because you're not passing an expression to the `LabelFor` method.

The above is much nicer and robust than an explicit for loop.